# Directx error y is undefined

Tags: c++, directx, undefined, directx-9

So Im trying to get a simple program from chillitomatoes tutorials to work but I get an error that I dont understand.

```
#include "D3DGraphics.h"

D3DGraphics::D3DGraphics( HWND hWnd )
{
    pDirect3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION );

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory( &d3dpp,sizeof( d3dpp ) );
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;
    d3dpp.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;

    pDirect3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,hWnd,
        D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING | D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE,&d3dpp,&pDevice );
}

D3DGraphics::~D3DGraphics()
{
    if( pDevice )
    {
        pDevice->Release();
        pDevice = NULL;
    }
    if( pDirect3D )
    {
        pDirect3D->Release();
        pDirect3D = NULL;
    }
}

void D3DGraphics::PutPixel( int x,int y,int r,int g,int b )
{
    IDirect3DSurface9* pBackBuffer = NULL;
    D3DLOCKED_RECT rect;

    pDevice->GetBackBuffer( 0,0,D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO,&pBackBuffer );
    pBackBuffer->LockRect( &rect,NULL,NULL );
    ((D3DCOLOR*)rect.pBits)[ x + (rect.Pitch >> 2) * y ] = D3DCOLOR_XRGB( r,g,b );
    pBackBuffer->UnlockRect();
    pBackBuffer->Release();
}


void D3DGraphics::BeginFrame()
{
    pDevice->Clear( 0,NULL,D3DCLEAR_TARGET,D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,0),0.0f,0 );
}

void D3DGraphics::EndFrame()
{
    pDevice->Present( NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL );
}

void D3DGraphics::DrawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2,int r, int g, int b)
{
    for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
    {
        PutPixel( x, y, r, g, b);
    }
}


//Here I have PutPixel(x,y,r,g,b); and It tells me y is undefined. but in the header file:

    class D3DGraphics
    {
    public:
        D3DGraphics( HWND hWnd );
        ~D3DGraphics();
        void PutPixel( int x,int y,int r,int g,int b );
        void DrawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
        void BeginFrame();
        void EndFrame();
    private:
    IDirect3D9*         pDirect3D;
    IDirect3DDevice9*   pDevice;
};
```

But as you can see, `y` is defined in `PutPixel`, and he didn't declare `y` to anything in `PutPixel` and he didn't put any decleration inside `DrawLine` for `y`.

Comment: The declaration also does not match the definition. Anyway, this looks more like something you should ask the author.

Comment: Show the error code instead mate, this is not helping at all.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error  IntelliSense: identifier "y" is undefined Chili DirectX Framework e:\Chili DirectX Framework\Assets\D3DGraphics.cpp 87

Comment: Show the class declaration.  Need to know if `y` is declared in the class.  The `y` variable in `DrawLine` need to be defined from somewhere.  See the call to `PutPixel`.